# How to pass data from one page into another using twin.macro

Tags: reactjs

I a bit new to react but trying to pass data from one page into another.

Page A:

```
const PlanAction = tw.div`px-4 sm:px-8 xl:px-16 py-8`;
const BuyNowButton = styled(PrimaryButtonBase)`
  ${tw`rounded-full uppercase tracking-wider py-4 w-full text-sm hover:shadow-xl transform hocus:translate-x-px hocus:-translate-y-px focus:shadow-outline`}
`;

...

  <PlanAction state={plan}>
    <BuyNowButton
      css={!plan.featured && highlightGradientsCss[index]}
      as="a"
      href="/payment"
      state={plan}
    >
      {primaryButtonText}
    </BuyNowButton>
  </PlanAction>
```

Page B:

```
  const location = useLocation();
```

I used location but only pathname is present, the state is undefined. I tried for couple of hours but don't understand why the data is not pass in other page. Thank you

edit Full code:

```
 <Container>
  <ContentWithPaddingXl>
    <HeaderContainer>
      {subheading && <Subheading>{subheading}</Subheading>}
      <Heading>{heading}</Heading>
      {description && <Description>{description}</Description>}
    </HeaderContainer>
    <PlansContainer>
      {(plans|| []).map((plan, index) => (
        <Plan key={index} featured={plan.featured}>
          {!plan.featured && <div className="planHighlight" css={highlightGradientsCss[index % highlightGradientsCss.length]} />}
          <PlanHeader>
            <span className="name">{plan.product_name}</span>
            <span className="price">$ {plan.price}</span>
            <span className="duration">{plan.duration}</span>
          </PlanHeader>
          <PlanFeatures>
            <span className="feature mainFeature">{plan.main_feature}</span>
            {Object.values(plan.features_representation).map((feature, index) => (
              <span key={index} className="feature">
                {feature}
              </span>
            ))}
          </PlanFeatures>
          <PlanAction state={plan}>
            <BuyNowButton css={!plan.featured && highlightGradientsCss[index]}
             as="a" href="/payment" state={"test"}
             >
              {primaryButtonText}

              </BuyNowButton>
          </PlanAction>
        </Plan>
      ))}
      <DecoratorBlob/>
    </PlansContainer>
  </ContentWithPaddingXl>
</Container>
```

Comment: Are you using react-router? Make sure you are passing the state prop to a react-router Link component inside BuyNowButton(PrimaryButtonBase). If not the case, share the code for PrimaryButtonBase so we can provide a clear answer

Comment: shared the code. Thank you

Comment: We actually need the code inside of the PrimaryButtonBase component

Comment: export const PrimaryButton = tw.button`px-8 py-3 font-bold rounded bg-primary-500 text-gray-100 hocus:bg-primary-700 hocus:text-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none transition duration-300`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a react-router link to pass a state, you could style a react-router link instead of a tw.button, maybe create something like a PrimaryButtonLink

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const PrimaryButtonLink = styled(Link)`
  ${tw`px-8 py-3 font-bold rounded bg-primary-500 text-gray-100 hocus:bg-primary-700 hocus:text-gray-200 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none transition duration-300`}
`;
```

Also, note that the [Link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object) component receives a `to` prop, not a href

```
const BuyNowButton = styled(PrimaryButtonLink)`
  ${tw`rounded-full uppercase tracking-wider py-4 w-full text-sm hover:shadow-xl transform hocus:translate-x-px hocus:-translate-y-px focus:shadow-outline`}
`;

...

<BuyNowButton
  css={!plan.featured && highlightGradientsCss[index]}
  to={{
    pathname:"/payment",
    state: "test", // not sure if state can be a string, try an object if it doesn't work
  }}
>
  {primaryButtonText}
</BuyNowButton>;
```